# Unable to get VS Code to access other code while debugging

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When I am debugging my python code it skips over code not written by me. I've set justmycode to false and I've tried updating request however, it won't accept any values except launch or attach and purpose is set to debug-test. Nothing seems to work.

My JSON file:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "justMyCode":false,
           "purpose": ["debug-test"]
       }
   ]
}
```

The message from the debugger(yes, I stepped in not over):

Frame skipped from debugging during step-in.
Note: may have been skipped because of "justMyCode" option (default == true). Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g., launch.json).

Sorry if this a stupid question I am a newbie and feeling totally over my head in my internship.

Literally this is my entire code. The message from the debugger appears when I try to step into execute().

```
pQuery=p.logquery()
pQuery.execute()
```

Comment: Are you maybe "stepping over" rather than "into"?

Comment: can you give a 3-4 line example of your code so we can try

Answer (score 1):

The official docs on how to do it are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests).

The OP was specifically adding a launch configuration for **debugging** tests. However, [over here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7347#issuecomment-530896261) it's mentioned you should set `"request": "test"` for "for justMyCode to work with test debugging".

```
{
  "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "test",
  "program": "${file}",
  "purpose": ["debug-test"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```

Which is not so clearly explained in the official docs... but worked for me.

---

In the most recent [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests), `"test"` is no longer a valid value for `"request"`. The following is recommended and worked for me:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "purpose": ["debug-test"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now and it suddenly started working when I set the `justMyCode` option to the end of the configuration **without** a comma at the end of the line.

So, **not working**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

And **working** example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot fathom why this is the case. If this works for you as well, please let me know.