# VSCode: cannot debug function from third-part library when inside a subprocess

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, pytorch, vscode-debugger

Edit: apparently this does not happen only in the subprocess, but also in a main process.

I'm trying to debug a Python script that uses an external module. Specifically, I'm trying to debug the load_state_dict function of a PyTorch model. However, when I try to step into the function using the debugger in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error message:

```
Frame skipped from debugging during step-in. Note: may have been skipped because of "justMyCode" option (default == true). Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g., launch.json).
Source: Subprocess 17299
```

I've tried setting "justMyCode": false in my launch.json file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I debug this function and step into the external module code using Visual Studio Code?

Code for reproducing:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

def train_a3c(rank, args, shared_model, counter, lock, num_steps, optimizer):
    model = SimpleModel()
    model.load_state_dict(shared_model.state_dict())

    # rest of the training code goes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = type('', (), {})()
    args.num_processes = 2
    args.num_steps = 10

    shared_model = SimpleModel().share_memory()
    counter = mp.Value('i', 0)
    lock = mp.Lock()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(shared_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    processes = []
    for rank in range(0, args.num_processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=train_a3c, args=(rank, args, shared_model, counter, lock, args.num_steps, optimizer))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

My launch.json:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: subprocess debugging, access external code",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "subProcess": true,
        },
```

Comment: How did you start debugging? You can use F5 or click `Run and Debug` button on the left menu, then click the triangle button. Here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209801/18359438), does that work for you?